# Simple multithreaded diffing on macOS

Tags: osx, diff, parallelism

I run `diff -rq` on terabyte-size directories in macOS. Is there a simple way to parallelize this process?

Comment: Usuallly diff is I/O limited. Can you confirm that your CPU indeed the limiting factor and that you are not limited by I/O?

Comment: Unless your directories span multiple physical drives, attached via multiple bus lines, IO is the limiting factor.